# Use and update data across more than one test in Cypress

Tags: cypress, fixtures

I am writing tests in Cypress and would like to get data in one test and use it in other tests. In this case, I am creating an object and I want to use the ID of that created object in later tests.

[Fixtures](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html) seem to be out. I can't set the object ID in a static file because I don't know it until the object is created. I have not found any documentation describing how to update data in a fixture while the tests run.

I have found the following workaround:

```js
describe('Data suite tests', function() {
    let objectId = 0;

    it('Create object', function() {
        cy.createObject(...);
        objectId = /* get id of created object from the resulting URL */
    });

    it('Another test', function() {
        cy.visit('/object/' + objectId);
    });
};
```

However, Cypress explicitly says to [avoid this pattern](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases) and to use Aliases instead.

I can not figure out whether it is possible to use an alias for my use-case. All of the provided examples describe getting the ID from the DOM. In my case I get it from the URL.

Also, all of the use cases describe setting an alias in a `beforeEach()` hook. But I can't do this because I must get it from inside one of the tests after the object is created.

Is there an approved way to do this using Cypress? Or is the use of a `let` variable the only possible workaround?

Comment: Can you [writeFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#Syntax) to the fixture folder? Subsequent tests then use `cy.fixture`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MarionMorrison. I found it was possible to use `readFile` and `writeFile` to do something like this using the `beforeEach()` hook. However, in my case I want to store the object data in a `json` file for other use cases (like a component library) and so I don't want the file to be overwritten whenever tests are run. I bent over backwards trying to read the file into a fixture and then modify it but I can't seem to get the modifications to persist across tests. Going to just go with a scoped `let` for now, I guess.